# How to set up Logback with tomcat 8?

Tags: tomcat, logback

I'm still facing issue with the configuration of Logback with tomcat8. I think I am missing a point.

> In my pom.xml:

`<!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>`

I added the valve in the server.xml file :

```
<Valve  className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                        directory="logs" 
                        prefix="localhost_access_log" 
                        suffix=".txt"
                        pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

> In logback.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
> <configuration scan="true">
>
>     <property name="max.retention.days" value="60" />
>
>     <appender name="GLOBAL_OUTPUT" class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
>         <file>global.log</file>
>         <append>true</append>
>         <encoder>
>             <charset>utf-8</charset>
>             <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level {%thread} [%logger{40}] : %msg%n</pattern>
>         </encoder>
>         <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.juli.logging.ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
>             <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/archive/global.log-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
>
>             <maxHistory>${max.retention.days}</maxHistory>
>             <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
>         </rollingPolicy>
>     </appender>    
>
>     <logger name="org.apache.catalina" level="INFO">
>         <appender-ref ref="GLOBAL_OUTPUT" />
>     </logger>
>
>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> And then in my logback-access.xml:
>
> ```
> <property name="max.retention.days" value="60" />
>
> <appender name="ACCESS-LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
>     <file>${catalina.base}/logs/localhost-access.log</file>
>     <append>true</append>
>     <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.access.PatternLayoutEncoder">
>         <charset>utf-8</charset>
>         <pattern>common</pattern>
>     </encoder>
>     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
>         <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/archive/localhost-access-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
>
>         <maxHistory>${max.retention.days}</maxHistory>
>         <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
>             <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize> 
>         </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
>     </rollingPolicy>
> </appender>
>
> <appender-ref ref="ACCESS-LOG" />
> ```
>
> And this is the error :
>
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
>   scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
>   logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
>   found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time.

Thanks for your help,
Swaye

Comment: I think i'm in the same boat as you are. I don't think the 'error' you quoted is your problem as I get that too. It's more of you are not seeing your application logs after that line.